# How to convert to id with conforming protocol?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspasteboard

Why is following code failed?

```
NSPasteboardItem* pasteboard_item = [NSPasteboardItem new];
id<NSPasteboardWriting> temp_obj = pasteboard_item;
```

I am newbie in Objective-c, but as I understand, `NSPasteboardItem` conforms `NSPasteboardWriting` protocol and such assignment should be allowed.

Xcode says:

> Cannot initialize a variable of type id with lvalue of type 'NSPasteboardItem*'

Note: `NSPasteboardItem` is the class from AppKit to work with `NSPasteBoard`

Comment: This compiles just fine on my machine. Are you remembering to import the entire Cocoa framework, and not just Foundation?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka, thnx for hint. I will check it out. Unfortunately I don't have access to mac at the moment.